# VS code runner executes in global environment despite being set up to use virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I set up a project directory, with a file importing a requests module. Then using pipenv I created a virtual environment and installed the request module. In the terminal window I activated the virtual environment and ran the file.

In VS Code editor I selected the interpreter for the environment (with the correct path) and ran the code using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. It returned:

> No module named 'requests'.

To check what is happening I created a file with `import sys` and `print(sys.version, sys.executable)`. Clearly the global version of Python is ran. What do I do wrong?

Here is the setting.json file for the project:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Periklis\\.virtualenvs\\Mosh_PyYelp-CK8YJ9nr\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by:

- In the global user file *settings.json* I manually defined the path to python in
  the virtual environment. In my case

  {
    "python.venvPath": "C:\Users\Periklis\.virtualenvs"
  }

  This ensured that appropriate interpreter can be selected from command pallet 
  “Python: Select Interpreter”.
- Once the interpreter is selected the path to the selected virtual
  environment is shown in the file *settings.json* that is placed in the .vscode
  sub-folder of the project folder. In my case

  {"python.pythonPath":
     "C:\Users\Periklis\.virtualenvs\Mosh_PyYelp-CK8YJ9nr\Scripts\python.exe"}
- In order to ensure that when running a python file via the editor
  (Alt + Ctrl +N) the appropriate interpreter is used I have manually
  inserted the full path to the interpreter into
  code-runner.executorMap section that was placed in the file
  *settings.json* in the sub-folder .vscode by copying the path to python
  in the virtual environment. In my case:

  {
  ...
  "code-runner.executorMap":{…., 
                             "python":
                              "C:\Users\Periklis\.virtualenvs\Mosh_PyYelp- 
                              CK8YJ9nr\Scripts\python.exe",
                              …}
  }

Now every python file in the project folder is executed within the virtual environment. Since I am new to VS Code and to programming in general I am not sure if this is the best way but it does work. I would love to hear about other options.